# Splittin off text after space in text file - Python

Tags: python, string

I want to read in a text file that has a bunch of rows that looks like this:

```
FIELD1 INTEGER DEFAULT -99999 ,
FIELD2 VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL,
FIELD3 INTEGER DEFAULT -99999 ,
FIELD4 INTEGER DEFAULT -99999 ,
FIELD5 INTEGER NOT NULL,
FIELD6...
```

What I want is to be able to write back to a different text file just the field names:

```
FIELD1
FIELD2
FIELD3
FIELD4
FIELD5
FIELD6
...
```

What would be the Python way of doing that? It looks like I need to split off everything in the row after the first space.

I tried this but got a: Unsupported operand: not readable
    import os

```
with open('test_text.txt', 'w') as f_in, open('my_file_edit.txt') as f_out:
    for line in f_in:
        new_str = ','.join(line.split(' ')[1:])
        f_out.write(new_str)
```

EDIT - Field names don't start with 'FIELD'.  I just used that as an example.  Field names are all different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you're opening `test_text.txt` as write. You should open any file you don't intend to write to as read. Next, let's create a list `content` which contains each line of the input text file:

```
with open('test_text.txt', 'r') as f_in:
    content = f_in.read().splitlines()
```

Then, you can use `.split()` on each line and write the first element of that array to your output file (which you should open this time as write):

```
with open('my_file_edit.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    for line in content:
        outString = line.split(' ')[0]
        f_out.write(outString + '\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.findall`:

```
import re
with open('test_text.txt', 'w') as f1, open('my_file_edit.txt') as f:
  fields = [re.findall('^\w+', i.strip('\n'))[0] for i in f]
  f1.write('\n'.join(fields))
```

Comment: sorry, not all field names start with 'FIELD'.  I just used those as examples.  They all have different names. I should have specified that